# Simplifying SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, count

I'm using the Bixi public dataset found at https://www.bixi.com/en/open-data and have been asked to find "the average number of trips a day for each year-month combination in the dataset". Here's an example of the table from which I'm querying:

| id | start_date | start_station_code | end_date | end_station_code | duration_sec | is_member |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85843 | 2016-04-15 00:00:00 | 6315 | 2016-04-15 00:05:00 | 6315 | 349 | 1 |
| 85844 | 2016-04-15 17:16:00 | 6315 | 2016-04-15 17:37:00 | 6315 | 1293 | 0 |

The query that I used to successfully answer the question was as follows, but how can I simplify it?:

```
SELECT
    daily_trips_2016.avg_daily_trips AS avg_daily_trips_2016,
    daily_trips_2017.avg_daily_trips AS avg_daily_trips_2017,
    daily_trips_2016.month
FROM
    (
    SELECT -- This sub-query determines the average number of daily trips per month for the year 2016
        ROUND(COUNT(*) / (COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(start_date))), 0) AS avg_daily_trips,
        MONTH(start_date) AS month
    FROM trips
    WHERE YEAR(start_date) = 2016
    GROUP BY month) AS daily_trips_2016
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT -- This sub-query determines the average number of daily trips per month for the year 2017
        ROUND(COUNT(*) / (COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(start_date))), 0) AS avg_daily_trips,
        MONTH(start_date) AS month
    FROM trips
    WHERE YEAR(start_date) = 2017
    GROUP BY month) AS daily_trips_2017
ON daily_trips_2016.month = daily_trips_2017.month; -- Since both sub-queries share the "month" column, the JOIN happens on this column
-- and we can see the daily averages side by side for each year
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? mysql <> sql server.

Comment: Sorry, should've specified, but I'm using MySQL

Comment: this query raises error `Invalid use of group function`

Comment: yes I'm getting that too

Comment: but why you explicitly mentioning year = 2016, 2017 ? rather you should add year to group by and show one extra column for year. How you will do it you've to solve the same for10 years data ?

Comment: I've edited the code block, copy pasting it directly from mine, I must've missed something before, but I just ran this and get the results I'm looking for so should work now.
That being said @iamawesome, my intention was to have the results of each month for the years 2016 and 2017 side by side and using GROUP BY year, month stacks the months of each year. In the end same results, but was more a question of what I wanted my output to look like I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(YEAR(start_date) = 2016) / COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN YEAR(start_date) = 2016 THEN DAY(start_date) END), 0)  AS avg_daily_trips_2016,
       ROUND(SUM(YEAR(start_date) = 2017) / COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN YEAR(start_date) = 2017 THEN DAY(start_date) END), 0)  AS avg_daily_trips_2017,
       MONTH(start_date) AS month
FROM trips
WHERE YEAR(start_date) IN (2016, 2017)
GROUP BY month;
```

Answer (score 0):

> find "the average number of trips a day for each year-month
> combination in the dataset".

```
SELECT ALL
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM start_date) AS period,
    COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(start_date)) AS avg_by_day
FROM trips
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

1 row by YYYYMM / average